# Есть массив объектов, как проверить есть ли в объектах пустые значения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Есть массив объектов, как проверить есть ли в объектах пустые значения?
Массив такого вида:

```js
var data = [
 {
  "test1": "",
  "test2": "2",
  },
  {
  "test1": "1",
  "test2": "2",
  },
  {
  "test1": "1",
  "test2": "",
  }
];
```

Собственно нужно, вывести в консоль "2", т.е. в массиве среди всех объектов есть 2 пустых значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [
 {
  "test1": "",
  "test2": "2",
  },
  {
  "test1": "1",
  "test2": "2",
  },
  {
  "test1": "1",
  "test2": "",
  }
];

let count_null = 0;
for(let val of data){
  for(let key in val){
    if(!val[key]){
      console.log(`${key} - пусто`);
      count_null++;
    }
  }
}
console.log(`Пустых занчений ${count_null}`);
```

Comment: При такой реализации `{
  "test1": "1",
  "test2": 0,
  }` тоже будет считаться пустым. Да и `{
  "test1": "1",
  "test2": false,
  }` тоже, что не есть хорошо.